# How to terminate a running program in c++

Tags: c++, system, exit, terminate, kill-process

I have written a program using C++, which I call

```
system("C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe");
```

to run the xampp control panel. When I run the program after compiling, it runs smoothly, except the program I have written is still running. Once the XAMPP control panel is launched, I want to terminate the program. What could possibly be done? Any help is much much appreciated.

Comment: The best scenario would be to not use `system()` to launch it. Instead, launch the new process using any system call that does it without blocking, and then simply `exit()` your program.

Comment: Maybe you can use `exit (int status);` if i understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job: [system documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) and relevant quote *"and returns after the command has been completed"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your application by the one being called with `exec`.

```
// Note: this waits for the exectued program to finish
// before the call to `system()` returns.
system("C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe");

// You can replace the current processes with the one you
// are starting like this.
execl("C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe", "xampp-control.exe");
// If this returns the applicaion failed to start.
std::cerr << "Failed to start application\n";
exit(1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Found a better alternative with `ShellExecute()`.. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate why it is not a better solution? :) Please don't take it as if I am teasing. I am a newbie to C++. So I am curious to know how things work around here...